Error displaying a custom error in the production version nextjs
I use the dynamic route [...not_found] in the group by calling nextjs not Found(). In development mode, opening a non-existent page works, but not in production mode, an empty page with reading errors is present in the browser console
//app/(site)/[...not_found]/page.js
import {notFound} from "next/navigation"
export default function NotFoundCatchAll() {
    notFound()
}

//app/(site)/not-found.js
import React from 'react';

const NotFound = () => {
    return <h1>Custom Error</h1>
};

export default NotFound;


 Error in Browser Console

package.json
"next": "^14.2.0",
"react": "^18.3.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",

there was an idea in app/(site)/[...not_found]/page.js to send the 404 page code, but I still haven't found how to do it in the app without calling the function notFound
